# Linear Independence of all rows with leading 1's

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a 5 x 8 matrix A, where it has a leading 1 for every row
eg:
\begin{pmatrix}
1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\\
0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\\
0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0
\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0
\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}
Are there still free variables even though all the available rows have a leading 1? Is this still a linearly independent set?

Comment: I see only one row with a leading 1.

Comment: @AndreasH. What do you mean? Don't all the rows have a leading 1?

Comment: Only the first one. The others have a leading 0, at least in my understanding. I do not understand what you mean. Also you should specify whether you want linearly independent rows or columns...

Comment: It certainly looks like there are 5 leading ones to me.

Comment: Also what is "free variables" supposed to mean?

Comment: @AndreasH.: Free variables are the variables with no fixed value. They can take on infinitely many values.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: Well, I know that. I just dont see any variables in the question. There are only numbers. I really have trouble getting the intention of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since there are more columns than rows, the vectors are linearly dependent. (Why?)

Comment: Because columns 6,7,8 are all free variables?

Comment: @user2989964: Exactly!

Comment: Not if one considers the rows as vectors (as one might guess from the title) ...